# RNN LSTM Keras custom loss function

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm beginning with Keras and TensorFlow.

I have an LSTM model learning on a dataset of stocks prices.
I don't want that my model learn to predict next steps like today. I want that my model learn on each step if it must buy, sell or do nothing and how much.

I think that I need to make a custom loss function, but I really don't know how to code my concept : buy, sell, nothing   and  how much based on a capital like 100 unit at beginning. The objective would be to have the hightest capital possible at the end.

- I must to use an existant function and customise it like MSE ? If yes, how ?
- I must to let my model learn the time series and after add a buy/sell layer(s) ? If yes, how ?
- Other ?

I am pretty lost.

Thank's a lot for your help.

Sam

Comment: What does your training data look like?
Do you only have access to stock prices or are there also decisions (buy, sell, nothing, how much) available?

Comment: My training data are only stock prices. I want that the model learn by itself the decisions (buy, sell, nothing, how much). I imagine a model wich don't really need to learn the time series but more the decisions each step to maximize the capital at the end. But perhaps I am wrong and it need to learn before time series and after the decisions. If I had code examples I could test that.

Comment: I see. I think you would definitely need to provide some hints to your model which decision is the right one.
Think of it this way: if someone just showed you a bunch of stock prices without ever telling you what they mean (imagine that you have no financial background), would you know what to make of that? A model is in some sense just like a completely naive child that doesn't know anything about the world. You have to give it some data that it can learn from.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but for me, it can exist a way to train the model without buying and selling  training data. Look, if i make my wieght and biases randomly each step and save model wich give the best capital at the end, it can work better than 50%. So with loss function to learn.. ^^. The question is how to code it :/.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not familiar with this kind of data, but how would you get the overall capital from the stock prices? Would this capital be for the whole system or by stock?

Your scenario is starting to sound as if you should look into reinforcement learning. Here's an introduction, but I recommend you read more into it before trying to train a model.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning

Comment: Hum, perhaps i don't know ^^. Very interesting i will read more about this, thanks. I hope that what i wan't to do is more easy/common to build ^^'.

Comment: Ho, and for answer i talked about the capital for the whole system. Give 100 at beginning and try to have the hightest capital for the whole series like 162. Do you know if i can build it with keras-rl ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try [categorical cross-entropy,](https://keras.io/losses/#categorical_crossentropy)

I mean you have three options: buy (0) , sell (1), and do nothing (2). You can encode it like this:

```
[1,0,0] < - means 'buy'
[0,1,0] < - means 'sell'
[0,0,1] < - means 'do nothing'
```

And don't forget to add softmax function in the end of you NN.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I will try it. Do you think that this function permit to answer of the "how much" question ? And base it on % of capital for buying and % of money outside for selling ?

Comment: Do note that this approach only really works if you have something to compare your decisions with. So you'd need to first acquire training data that contains information about which (presumably correct) decision was made.

Comment: @Samantha I think you can try something like a two-staged approach. Where the first one is the action determination (buy, sell, nothing), and the second stage is the answer for "how much?". 

So, if you got a prediction from the first stage to buy, using the second stage (another NN) you are predicting the amount. 

Actually, you can do it with a single NN model just using two outputs, for the action and amount answers.

Comment: Do you think that i can do the first step without buy, sell, nothing training data? My idea was to look only the whole system capital at the end but this method can't work with that no?

Comment: @Samantha, unfortunately no, if you don't have training data, I would recommend to have a look for a Reinforce Learning approach.

Comment: :/ Llia Kurendov said the same thing. Il will look it then, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand, we have stock prices dataset and at each point, we are required to predict the decision buy/sell/nothing.

For each point, we should decide a window size, which we believe impact the current point.
Use this window as time series input to LSTM layer. Using moving window, we can create multiple inputs. The corresponding output will be the decision, which can be taken to be encoded 3 bits.

1. For time point t, use time series (0..t-1) as input. and decision [0,0,1] or [0,1,0] or [1,0,0] as output. The model will learn to predict probabilities for each decision.
2. To compute loss, [categorical cross entropy](https://keras.io/losses/#categorical_crossentropy) will be useful, as mentioned by Paddy.

Also, if you haven't looked into pre-processing data, detrending the data is useful in such cases. This [link](http://rpubs.com/ryankelly/tsa2) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pre-processing informations ! Do you think that your way works with what Llia Kurendov said ? He said that without buying and selling traning data, this way can't train a model with only the hightest capital possible at the end.